# iOS - presentViewController with transparency

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I would like to present a view controller full screen semi-transparently so that I still see the view underneath it. The following code presents the new view controller, but it replaces the current one. What is the best way to keep the original view controller visible? The view of the new view controller will have a semi-transparent black background.

```
NewViewController* newVC = [[NSClassFromString(@"NewViewController") alloc] initWithNibName:deviceNib bundle:nil];
newVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
newVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;


[self presentViewController:newVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Present a semi-transparent View, not a view controller.

```
mySemiTransparentView.alpha = 0.0f;
[self.view addSubview:mySemiTransparentView];
```

mySemiTransparentView is your full-screen view.  You can animate it into place:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeIn" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
mySemiTransparentView.alpha = 0.5f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: True, but I would like to use the view controller.

Comment: You can still instantiate your UIViewController via alloc/init, then mySemiTransparentView can just be your ViewController.view

Comment: Unless you want everything on your semitransparent view to be .5 alpha (including buttons and such), don't set the alpha of the view, because it cascades to all subcomponents.  You are better off creating a background view that takes up the entire screen that is .5 alpha, and then layering your buttons and such onto that.

Answer (score 2):

You can present semi-transparent modal controller in the following way:

```
NewViewController* newVC = [[NSClassFromString(@"NewViewController") alloc] initWithNibName:deviceNib bundle:nil];

self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
newVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentViewController:newVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Notice here that you have to set the constant *UIModalPresentationCurrentContext* to **self**.modalPresentationStyle, not to **newVC**.modalPresentationStyle

Furthermore, when you use *UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve* the alpha of the *newVC.view* will be overridden during the transition, so if you want semi-transparent background you'll need to keep *newVC.view*'s *backgroundColor* clear and just add another UIView as it's subview with semi-transparent *backgroundColor*

Comment: `self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;` or `newVC. modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom`and + 1 also for the second part of your answer. Thanks